# Let .. in statement doesn't work in IO?

Tags: haskell

I can hardly make the difference between "where" and "let .. int" statements.
Here's my code. I want 2 ways to print 5.

```
main =  do
    print x
      where x = 5
    let x = 5 in print x
```

First one works, but I get a "parse error on input 'let'"
Is this a matter of indentation, or is my code plain wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`where` always ends a statement; nothing should go after `where`.
So, you could write it like this:

```
main = do
    let x = 5 in print x
    print x
        where x = 5
```

This is valid because the `where` clause ends the statement, where it should belong. Your code was invalid because the parser expected to find nothing after the `where x = 5`, but discovered your `let` clause.

Comment: What is a statement? Anyway, "nothing should go after `where`" is imprecise. For example, `do { case () of { () -> return () where { () = () } }; return () }` is perfectly valid Haskell (fully braced and semicolon'd for clarity).

Answer (score 3):

Your code is wrong. The `where` clause must occur at the end of the definition, while `let` is an expression that could occur anywhere an expression is valid.